# Convert .shp into .tif using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I have some .tif world image with 1km x 1km spatial resolution. I also have .shp file with 2km x 2km grid data. I need to convert .shp file into .tif in the same spatial resolution and projection as .tif world image.

Is it possible to process in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

- rasterize your shape : Raster>Conversion>Rasterize
- save as GTiff. There you can check if proj and resolution are ok

Answer (score 2):

Go `Raster->Conversion->Rasterize`.  In the dialog box set the resolution of the output you want either as the size of the output or pixels.  You can be more exact in terms of extent of the final raster (to ensure it matches the tif file exactly) by editing the gdal_rasterize command that is auto generated in the bottom text box.  See the documentation for [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) for more information on the various settings.